# Apache LocationMatch regex with subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, subdomain, locationmatch

I'm trying to use LocationMatch to match an URL in a website's second-level subdomain but not in it's third-level subdomain. This is because I want to password protect some URLs at that level.

eg. `level2.domain.com/some/url` should match but not `level3.level2.domain.com/some/url`

Than I would apply the necessary directives to password protect the URLs.

Does LocationMatch match this part or the URL ? I don't think so, and if that's the case, what could I use to achieve the desired effect ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to break up the locations into separate `VirtualHost` blocks and use `ServerName` / `ServerAlias` appropriately to specify the domains you want to cover...